# Load image from a folder using URL from database in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In an `ASP.NET MVC` application, `file` is successfully saved to a folder and its `URL` is saved to `SQL database`. `URL` is saved in an `Absolute URL` form i.e., (D:\Visual Studio Projects\HRMS\HRMS\App_Data\photos\5.png). Having problem in loading `file` in a browser from folder using this `URL`. Code implementation is:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("UploadPhoto")]
public ActionResult UploadPhoto(HttpPostedFileBase photoPath)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(photoPath.FileName);
    if (photoPath.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/photos"), fileName);
        photoPath.SaveAs(path);
    }
    ViewBag.upload = "Success! Photo was uploaded successfully.";
    string fpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/photos"), fileName);
    TempData["filePath"] = fpath;
    return RedirectToAction("CreateWithImage", new { path = fpath });
}

public ActionResult CreateWithImage(string path)
{
    employee em = new employee();
    em.districts = new SelectList(hc.districts, "name", "name");
    string fp = Convert.ToString(TempData["filePath"]);
    em.photoPath = fp;
    return View(em);
}
```

file (image) is rendered in a view as:

```
@model HRMS.Models.employee
<dd>
    <img src="@Url.Content(@Model.photoPath)" />
</dd>
```

When View is called, I see a broken link for the image. HTML(with correct file path) for the loaded page (View) is seen as:

```
<dd>                
    <img src="D:\Visual Studio Projects\HRMS\HRMS\App_Data\photos\5.png" />
</dd>
```

Can someone note the problem and guide accordingly?

Comment: Answer to above question can be seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929929/image-not-displaying-in-asp-net-mvc)!. Thank you.

Comment: @mohit if you have deleted your answer, kindly delete this above comment as well and upvote the question if you think it has added to your knowledge or research. Thank you.

Comment: I had already upvoted it

Comment: @mohit For some strange reason, I can't see it here but thank you. :)

Comment: You had minus one point before now u have 0

Comment: Oh .. got it :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Remove the Image from App_Data folder because it is a hidden Segment section and hence the application is denied access to that folder.

Just Create a New Folder outside the app_data folder.

You can now access the image in two ways

1. Relative path
   Example: `../photos/5.png`
2. Absolute path
   Example:
   [http://localhost:portnumber/photos/5.png]

**Helpful Tip**:Once you run the application you can use the absolute path in the browser to see if the image  is accessible. If  you are not able to access it will tell u the physical path where it is trying to search that image. With this you will be easy able to fix the absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a URL, it's a file system path:

```
D:\Visual Studio Projects\HRMS\HRMS\App_Data\photos\5.png
```

The two are very different things.  You *might* be able to get away with a `file://` URL, *maybe*:

```
file://D/Visual Studio Projects/HRMS/HRMS/App_Data/photos/5.png
```

But it would make infinitely more sense to just use an *actual URL*.  Something like:

```
/App_Data/photos/5.png
```

(Or an absolute URL, something relative to the current page, etc.)

So saving the path might look something more like this:

```
var path = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/App_Data/photos/" + fileName);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sorry your suggestion isn't working. Image is still coming as broken and rendered HTML is `<dd>
            <img src="/App_Data/photos/16.GIF" />
        </dd>`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your existing  line-

```
TempData["filePath"] = fpath;
```

With

```
TempData["filePath"] = Url.Content("~/App_Data/photos/" + fileName);
```