# Image not displaying in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In an `ASP.NET MVC` application, `file` is successfully saved to a folder and its `URL` is saved to `SQL database`. Having problem in loading `file` in a browser from folder using this `URL`. Code implementation is:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ActionName("UploadPhoto")]
    public ActionResult UploadPhoto(HttpPostedFileBase photoPath)
    {
         var fileName = Path.GetFileName(photoPath.FileName);
        string path;
        if (photoPath.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/photos"), fileName);
            photoPath.SaveAs(path);
        return RedirectToAction("CreateWithImage", new { path = path });
        }
return View();
    }

public ActionResult CreateWithImage(string path)
    {
        employee em = new employee();
        em.districts = new SelectList(hc.districts, "name", "name");
        em.photoPath = path;
        return View(em);
    }
```

file (image) is rendered in a view as:

```
@model HRMS.Models.employee
<dd>
        @Html.Image(@Model.photoPath)
    </dd>
```

Extension method implementation for `@Html.Image` is:

```
    namespace HRMS.CustomeHTMLHelper
{
    public static class CustomHtmlHelper
    {
        public static IHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper,string src)
        {
            TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("img");
            tb.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(src));
            return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
        }
    }
}
```

When View is called, I see a broken link for the image. HTML(with correct file path) for the loaded page (View) is seen as:

```
<dd>                
            <img src="/App_Data/photos/1.png" />
            </dd>
```

When I try to run the physical path to the image in the browser i.e., `<b>Requested URL</b>    http://localhost:57852/App_Data/photos/1.png`, it is throwing `HTTP Error 404.8 - Not Found` Error.

Where could I be wrong? Please help.

Comment: Not related but remove `ViewBag.upload = "Success! Photo was uploaded successfully.";` - your redirecting so that will do nothing. And remove `TempData["filePath"] = fpath;` and `string fp = Convert.ToString(TempData["filePath"]);` and use `em.photoPath = path;

Comment: Next, declare `string path; before the `if` block and use just `path = Path.Combine(...);` inside the loop. Then delete `string fpath = "~/App_Data/photos/" + fileName;` and use `return RedirectToAction("CreateWithImage", new { path = path });`

Comment: And a `404.8` error usually means your being denied requests to files in `_AppData` (which is the default). Suggest you create another folder in your app (say `\Images\photos`), copy the file there and try it with that path.

Comment: @StephenMuecke All is good now. Thank you very much for helping.